# Regex function to make a word title case (including hyphens)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a `regex` that gets me 95% of the way there:

```
var string = element.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s\u2014\u002E]*) */g, function(txt){
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
})
```

The regex should take any string and return it in title case. For instance:

`hello -> Hello` // Works

`hElLo mY nAme Is -> Hello My Name Is` // Works

`What-did-you-say-to-me? -> What-Did-You-Say-To-Me?` // Does not work (all characters after hyphens are returning lowercase.

If there are any other scenarios that I haven't considered please let me know. I don't want special characters other than full stops and dashes to be counted (for instance, I don't want to capitalise after an apostrophe).

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan That doesn't work with apostrophes, e.g. "don't" would turn to "Don'T" instead of "Don't".

Comment: @BrianRogers Good catch.  `/[\w']+/` (it occurs to me the word boundaries aren't necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the word boundary assertion `\b` to more easily find words:

```
/\b[\w']+\b/g
```

This will find the starting word boundary, all "word" characters and apostrophes, followed by another word boundary. Since dashes should count as word boundaries, this should catch your problem text.